# Using variable in WPBakery custom query

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

I'm trying to create a custom query that uses a variable in the query. I can accomplish this using these instructions (from a comment on [this](https://www.design33.net/blog/how-to-visual-composers-grid-custom-query/) blog post):

> If you need to pass a variable, edit the file
>   js_composer/include/classes/shortcodes/vc-basic-grid.php
>
> //FILTER CUSTOM SHORTCODE BY ADDING DATE
>
> $date_today = date(‘Ymd’);
>
> $post_data = query_posts( str_replace(‘TODAY_DATE_CUSTOM’, $date_today, $query) );
>
> //$post_data = query_posts( $query );

The only problem is I don't like modifying the source code of a plugin, so I was wondering if there's another way around this, or, at the very least, a way to override this particular file in my child theme?